# Create shine effect over a text element dynamically via a function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want a function to dynamically create a shine effect over a text element.

Unfortunately I can't create it without a hand.

Here is what I have tried: (it doesn't work at all)

```js
function Shine() {
    const el = document.querySelector(".text-element-style");
    el.classList.remove("shine");
    setTimeout(() => el.classList.add("shine"), 10); 
}


setTimeout(() => Shine(), 2500);
```

```css
html {
  background-color: #333;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  padding-top: 3em;
}

.text-element-style {
  position: relative;
  font-family: "Open Sans Semibold", sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 5vw;
  color: #ff0000;
  opacity: 1;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.shine {
  background: #222 -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#222), to(#222), color-stop(0.5, #fff)) 0 0 no-repeat;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-40deg, transparent 0%, transparent 40%, #fff 50%, transparent 60%, transparent 100%);
  -webkit-background-size: 200px;
  color: #ff0000;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-animation-name: shine;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes shine {
  0%, 10% {
    background-position: -1000px;
  }
  20% {
    background-position: top left;
  }
  90% {
    background-position: top right;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 1000px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="text-element-style shine">Shine Bright Like a Diamond</div>
```

**Note:** the shine effect should be reusable on single element (we may shine the element more than once)

NOTE: [the code has been adapted from this Codepen please have a look.](https://codepen.io/pixy-dixy/pen/qBaYWoP)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I understood the question correctly, but I see the solution like this:

```css
html { background-color: #333; text-align: center; }
body { padding-top: 3em; margin: 0; }

.text-element-style {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  font: 5vw "Open Sans Semibold", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #3338;
  opacity: 1;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 10px #fff4) drop-shadow(1px .13em 1px black);
}

.shine {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-40deg, transparent 0%, transparent 40%, #fff 50%, transparent 60%, transparent 100%), url(https://3djungle.ru/upload/resize_cache/iblock/cff/400_400_1/cffd2eb9edbe2ba2925ec99cc90f76dd.jpg);
  background-position: -100%, 0%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
  background-size: 10em, auto;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  /* If you need an effect without hovering, then drag the animation here */
  animation: none;
}
.shine:hover {
  /* If you need a single shine, then remove the infinite */
  animation: shine 3s linear infinite;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@-webkit-keyframes shine {
  from { background-position: -100%, 0%; }
  to { background-position: 200%, 0%; }
}
```

```html
<div class="text-element-style shine">Shine Bright Like a Diamond</div>

<ul class="text-element-style">
  <li class="shine">Shine</li>
  <li>Bright</li>
  <li class="shine">Like</li>
  <li>Diamond</li>
</ul>

<p>I want a function to dynamically create a <span class="shine">shine effect</span> over a text element.<br>
Unfortunately I can't create it without a hand.<br>
Here is what I have tried: (it doesn't <span class="shine">work at all</span>)</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, plus one, please have a look at my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65568153/text-shining-effect-not-working-properly-how-can-i-fix-this